# iconv for Elixir

Tags: utf-8, elixir, iconv

I download a CSV file and save it with this code:

```
body = HTTPoison.get!(url).body 
       |> String.replace("Ã¼", "ü") 
       |> String.replace("Ã¶", "ö")
File.write!("/tmp/example.csv", body)
```

To do the `String.replace/3` to replace `Ã¼` with `ü` is of course not a good way. HTTPoison tells me that the body is `{"Content-Type", "csv;charset=utf-8"}`.

How can I solve this without `String.replace/3`?

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/tallakt/codepagex (never tried it, but its README says it's "iconv in 100% pure Elixir", which sounds like what you're looking for) ?

Comment: Is it possible to share the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is data that is first UTF-8 encoded, then the bytes are treated as latin1 encoding and encoded to UTF-8 again.

A hex dump snippet from the data in that URL shows this:

```
00007d20: 2c22 222c 2c2c 224f 7269 6769 6e3a 2044  ,"",,,"Origin: D
00007d30: c383 c2bc 7373 656c 646f 7266 222c 224b  ....sseldorf","K
00007d40: 6579 776f 7264 733a 204c 6173 7420 4d69  eywords: Last Mi
```

`ü` is encoded as `<<0xc3, 0x83, 0xc2, 0xbc>>` which was probably created like this:

```
iex(1)> "ü\0"
<<195, 188, 0>>
iex(2)> <<195::utf8, 188::utf8>> == <<0xc3, 0x83, 0xc2, 0xbc>>
true
```

To reverse this process, you can use a combination of `:unicode.characters_to_list` and `:erlang.list_to_binary`.

```
iex(3)> <<0xc3, 0x83, 0xc2, 0xbc>> |> :unicode.characters_to_list |> :erlang.list_to_binary
"ü"
```

---

That URL also includes a BOM at the start:

```
00000000: efbb bf22 5a75 7069 6422 2c22 5072 6f67  ..."Zupid","Prog
          ^^^^ ^^
00000010: 7261 6d49 6422 2c22 4d65 7263 6861 6e74  ramId","Merchant
00000020: 5072 6f64 7563 744e 756d 6265 7222 2c22  ProductNumber","
```

This can be removed using `|> Enum.drop(1)` after `:unicode.characters_to_list`.

So the following should work for you:

```
HTTPoison.get!(url).body
|> :unicode.characters_to_list
|> Enum.drop(1)
|> :erlang.list_to_binary
```